# C# Having Trouble with Property Variables (get and set)

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, properties

Im having some trouble understanding how Properties work in C#. A quick bit of background first: Im working on a level manager in unity, its purpose is to contain a list of game levels and information for each of them(level description, level image etc) and all this is saved in a single ScriptableObject.

So lets say i have 3 properties, sceneIndex, sceneName and LevelID.

**sceneIndex** is a variable that i should be able to change in unity's inspector and should match a levels index in the build settings.

**sceneName** should not be editable in unity's inspector and should always be the name of the level. (this is determined by the sceneIndex)

**LevelID** should always be set to the index of this class in the level list.

Here is my current code - currently when i change the sceneIndex, my sceneName isnt updating to the matching name in the inspector, and the LevelID isnt updating when i add new elements to my List.

```
public class LevelDataBase : ScriptableObject {

    [System.Serializable]
    public class LevelData {

        [SerializeField]
        public string p_sceneName{//the levelName
            get{ return sceneName; } 
            set{ sceneName = SceneManager.GetSceneAt (sceneIndex).name; }// it should always be set depending on the Scene Index
        }
        public string sceneName;//Properties dont display in unity's inspector so i have to use  secondary variable for it to be displayed.

        public int sceneIndex;//the scene index i should be able to change and then the scene Name should Updatedepending on the value


        [SerializeField]
        public int p_LevelID {//the Level id Should always be the index of this class in the list.
            get{ return LevelID; }
            set{ LevelID = LevelList.IndexOf (this); }
        }
        public int LevelID;

        public string DisplayName;
        public Sprite Image;
        public string Description;
    }

    public List<LevelData> LevelList;//this is a list containing all the levels in the game
}
```

Thanks ~Scott

Comment: "doesnt work" - is not a proper description.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are misunderstanding the way properties work. You use  `set{ sceneName = SceneManager.GetSceneAt (sceneIndex).name; }` as if it would describe the way it should work (some kind of property based development).

Properties are used to encapsulate the fields. Thus they provide a kind of "get" and "set" feature. The set feature will only be called when using MyProperty=value; and the get property will be triggered by value=MyProperty.

so it feels like your set should be renamed in get and you should get rid of your previous get.

```
 public string SceneName{//the levelName
            get{ return SceneManager.GetSceneAt (sceneIndex).name; }// it should always be set depending on the Scene Index
        }
```

And then in your code you should always access this data using SceneName rather than the public string sceneName (which is probably useless now).

Edit: using a setter:

```
public int SceneIndex{
    set
    { 
        sceneIndex = value;
        sceneName= SceneManager.GetSceneAt (sceneIndex).name; }// it should always be set depending on the Scene Index
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Bruno Thanks for they Reply. Yeah did misunderstand how properties worked so thanks for explaining that. But the reason i have to use the "public string sceneName" Variable, is becasue a properly isnt displayed in unity's inspector. that is why im using a second variable and changing it when the property is meant to be changed.

Comment: I'am not used to unity but it seems stange to me that properties are ignored. Anyway, what you can do is using a setter to modify the sceneIndex which would update the sceneName as well. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: So i messed around and implemented your code snippets. Now is does work, if i call at runtime "SceneIndex = 1;" the sceneIndex and sceneName are updated. the only problem is that, since im changing the sceneIndex (variable not property) in unity's inspector the property value is never changed and therefor isnt calling "set" and not updating the sceneName.

Comment: I think at this stage it might be quicker to just write a customInspector for the database, the original idea was to just include all the code(and have varaibles update) in one script, but i dont think that is going to work.